# Must I escape ALL outputted variables with htmlspecialchars?

Tags: php

I understand the need to use htmlspecialchars to escape output when displaying it on a web page.

I just wondered though, do I need to do that for EVERY single piece of data that I output, or only those bits of data which a user might have control over?

For example, the first block of code below has no escaping in place, and the 2nd has everything escaped.

Would I need to escape even an ID from a database, and a variable which is only set within the page?

Or only the variables which contain data which a user can edit - in the example below, that would be $post_label and $post_content.

Code before escaping:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){

    $post_id =      $row['ID'];
    $post_date =    $row['post_date'];
    $post_content = $row['post_content'];
    $post_label =   $row['post_label'];
    $fld_cat =      $row['fld_cat'];
    $post_day_num = date('N', strtotime($post_date));

    if ($post_day_num > 5) {
        $css = "success";
    } else {
        $css = "info";
    }

    $recent .= "<div class='alert alert-$css'>\n";
    $recent .= "    <div>\n";
    $recent .= "        <strong>" . date('D d-M-Y', strtotime($post_date)) . " | $fld_cat</strong> | \n";
    $recent .= "        <a href='default.php?id=$post_id&amp;mode=edit'>Edit</a> | \n";
    $recent .= "        <a href='default.php?id=$post_id&amp;mode=delete'>Delete</a>\n";
    $recent .= "    </div>\n";
    $recent .= "    <div>$post_content</div>\n";
    $recent .= "</div>\n";

}
```

Code after escaping:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){

    $post_id =      htmlspecialchars($row['ID']);
    $post_date =    htmlspecialchars($row['post_date']);
    $post_content = htmlspecialchars($row['post_content']);
    $post_label =   htmlspecialchars($row['post_label']);
    $fld_cat =      htmlspecialchars($row['fld_cat']);
    $post_day_num = htmlspecialchars(date('N', strtotime($post_date)));

    if ($post_day_num > 5) {
        $css = "success";
    } else {
        $css = "info";
    }

    $recent .= "<div class='alert alert-$css'>\n";
    $recent .= "   <div>\n";
    $recent .= "       <strong>" . date('D d-M-Y', strtotime($post_date)) . " | $fld_cat</strong> | \n";
    $recent .= "       <a href='default.php?id=$post_id&amp;mode=edit'>Edit</a> | \n";
    $recent .= "       <a href='default.php?id=$post_id&amp;mode=delete'>Delete</a>\n";
    $recent .= "   </div>\n";
    $recent .= "   <div>$post_content</div>\n";
    $recent .= "</div>\n";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that every time you echo data from the database into HTML, it should be ran through this method so that it is interpreted correctly and does not break your markup or cause security vulnerabilities.

Of course, if you have absolute control over the output - this is not something to necessarily worry about. A core guideline is however that you never have absolute control.

Answer (score 0):

Only escape user input. Ids or other stuff that come from the database or from your own code cannot be manipulated by a user with malicious intents.

Remember that the primary reason for escaping strings is to prevent Cross-Site-Scripting attacks. Input that does not come from the user can't possibly contain XSS code.